# Prevent whitespace around XML comments in QDomDocument::toString()

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom

I process an XML (XHTML) document using `QDomDocument`, as easy as this example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><i>foo</i><!-- comment --><b>bar</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As an (X)HTML document, the text should be rendered without a whitespace in between "foo" and "bar", since a comment in (X)HTML will not produce a whitespace (unless surrounded by some):

> *foo***bar**

However, when parsed by `QDomDocument` and then stringified using `.toString()`, I get the following source back:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   <i>foo</i>
   <!-- comment -->
   <b>bar</b>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is then rendered with a whitespace:

> *foo*
>   
>   **bar**

As I understand it, the output of `QDomDocument` seems to be a *different* XML document than the original one. I checked by inspection of the document tree that the parsed document *does not contain the whitespace*: The `<i>` element is immediately followed by a comment node which is followed by the `<b>` element; i.e. no text node in between.

The fact that the multi-whitespaces don't match (i.e. the indentation width) is not a problem (IIRC, the XML spec doesn't distinguish between multiple whitespaces and a single one, so does HTML). But for two tags with no whitespace in between originally, I require the output to also have no whitespace.

Is this a bug in `QDomDocument::toString()`? How can I work around this problem? Can I prevent `QDomDocument::toString()` to produce whitespace here? I already tried to pass `-1` as the optional parameter `indent`, which is documented as: ["no whitespace at all is added"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#toString). It will however still add a line break *after* the comment (but not before). I could imagine implementing a custom serializer, but I don't know if it is as easy as I imagine.

Comment: If you itereate through the document and find the comment and look at the comment element, does it have a trailing space?

Comment: @Surt Thanks for your comment. The comment node itself can't have a whitespace, since whitespace would be a *text node*. The content of the comment is exactly `" comment "` (i.e. there are whitespaces but they are because I entered them inside the `<!-- ... -->` and if I remove it they're gone). The child nodes of `<p>` are: element `<i>`, comment, element `<b>`. The child node of element `<i>` is a text with value `"foo"`.

Comment: Interestingly, if I re-parse the document (i.e. `doc.setContent(doc.toString())`), I get the exact same tree (without a text between the `<i>` and the comment or between the comment and the `<b>`. So it seems that Qt treats it as if it wouldn't make a difference if there is whitespace or it isn't. But when rendering it as an XHTML document, it makes a difference.

Comment: I just double-checked that the document is really displayed as an XHTML document in the browser (it at least shows the mime type `application/xhtml+xml` and also says it renders in "Standards compliance mode"). Tested with Firefox.

Comment: Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpn33zqp/) comparing the two snippets. In this fiddle, I set DTD = XHTML 1.0 Strict